# How can you use SCSS modules in React?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I know we can use `style.module.css`, but is it possible to use `style.module.scss`? Is there a dependency that can help us do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You have to simply install `node-sass` package and then you can use files like `style.module.scss`.